# How to query SSAS Datasource ConnectionString Properties

Tags: sql-server-2016, ssas, mdx

I've been asked to audit the Connection strings used by our SSAS OLAP cubes and where they are *sourcing data from*.

I can view the properties manually and can even script them:

> Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=DEV-SERVER;Integrated
>   Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=EnviroDataMart

But I can't figure out how to query them. Can this be done with SQL or MDX?

Comment: 9 months later I'm trying to sovle the same problem again and found my own post.

Comment: I solved it with Powershell: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/242302/use-powershell-to-query-ssas-connection-string/242305#242305